# What is magnitude of sum of two vector?

Tags: calculus, normed-spaces

I know that magnitude of $ X$ is defined as:

$$\|X\|=\sqrt {( {X\cdot X})}$$

Now if I define $ X$ as the sum of two vector like this $ X= X_1+ X_2$

then what will be the magnitude of:

$$\| X_1+ X_2\|=?$$

Comment: If you do some experiments with actual numbers, you may be able to convince yourself that the magnitude of the sum can't be deduced from the magnitude of the summands.

Answer (score 21):

The magnitude is given by the same formula as the one you gave, that is,
$$\sqrt{(X_1+X_2)\cdot(X_1+X_2)}.$$

We can play around with this formula in various ways. For example, we have
$$(X_1+X_2)\cdot (X_1+X_2)=X_1\cdot X_1+X_2\cdot X_2 +2 X_1\cdot X_2.$$

Note  that $X_i\cdot X_i=\Vert X_i\Vert^2$. Also, $X_1\cdot X_2=\Vert X_1\Vert \Vert X_2\Vert \cos\theta,$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors. So an alternate expression for the magnitude of the sum is
$$\sqrt{\Vert X_1\Vert^2+ \Vert X_2\Vert^2+ 2\Vert X_1\Vert \Vert X_2\Vert \cos\theta}.$$

Comment: Note: if X1 and X2 are unit vectors, then we have `sqrt(2 + 2 cos(theta))` => `sqrt(2 + 2 (cos2(theta/2) - 1))` (by double angle formula) => `sqrt(4 cos2(theta/2))` => `2 cos(theta/2)`

Answer (score 1):

The magnitude of the vectors does not uniquely determine the magnitude of the sum. However what you can do is to use the triangle inequality to get an upper and a lower bound for the possible magnitudes.

Comment: Yes, @achmed, this is exactly why the triangle inequality is useful. It can be expressed as $\|a\| - \|b\| \leq \|a \pm b\| \leq \|a\| + \| b \|$